# Reshaping Dataframe to have top 2 values

Tags: r, casting, dplyr, reshape

```
FAMILY<- c('FAMILYA', 'FAMILYA', 'FAMILYA', 'FAMILYA', 'FAMILYA', 'FAMILYB', 'FAMILYB', 'FAMILYB', 'FAMILYB', 'FAMILYB', 'FAMILYC', 'FAMILYC', 'FAMILYC', 'FAMILYC', 'FAMILYC')

CHILDREN<-c('JAKE', 'PETE', 'JASON', 'KEVIN', 'ALFRED','DALE', 'STEVE', 'MELISSA', 'DAN', 'THOMAS', 'CAIT', 'BRANDON', 'DEAN', 'ADAM', 'KELSEY')

CHANGE<-c(1000, -1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 100, 300, 1234, -1022, -1111, -1112, 1000, 1002, 2131, 1231)

df1<-data.frame(FAMILY, CHILDREN, CHANGE)

df1

    FAMILY CHILDREN CHANGE
1  FAMILYA     JAKE   1000
2  FAMILYA     PETE  -1000
3  FAMILYA    JASON   2000
4  FAMILYA    KEVIN   3000
5  FAMILYA   ALFRED   5000
6  FAMILYB     DALE    100
7  FAMILYB    STEVE    300
8  FAMILYB  MELISSA   1234
9  FAMILYB      DAN  -1022
10 FAMILYB   THOMAS  -1111
11 FAMILYC     CAIT  -1112
12 FAMILYC  BRANDON   1000
13 FAMILYC     DEAN   1002
14 FAMILYC     ADAM   2131
15 FAMILYC   KELSEY   1231
```

I want to transform this dataframe to have 4 new extra columns: First two showing the 1) largest valued Child, 2) 2nd Largest valued Child and the last two columns showing the 3) smallest value Child, 4) 2nd Smallest value Child.

I would also like the Change next to it's respective Child.

Final format should look like this:

```
 FAMILY  TOTAL CHANGE       INCREASE #1      INCREASE #2       DECREASE #1      DECREASE #2
FAMILYA         10000      ALFRED: 5000      KEVIN: 3000       PETE: -1000       JAKE: 1000 
FAMILYB          -499     MELISSA: 1234       STEVE: 300     THOMAS: -1111       DAN: -1022 
FAMILYC          4252        ADAM: 2131     KELSEY: 1231       CAIT: -1112    BRANDON: 1000
```

If you think it would be easier to have the values of each child in a separate column next to it that works too but this is the concept I need help executing.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# below function helps to get the second max  or second min 
myfun <-  function(x, y) {
  u <- unique(x)
  u <- sort(u, decreasing = TRUE)
  if(y<0)
    u[length(x)-1]
  else
    u[y]
}

df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(FAMILY) %>% 
      summarise(a1=CHILDREN[which(CHANGE == max(CHANGE))]   , a2 = max(CHANGE), 
                b2 = myfun(CHANGE, 2)          , b1=CHILDREN[which(CHANGE == b2)] ,  
                c1=CHILDREN[which(CHANGE == min(CHANGE))]   , c2 = min(CHANGE), 
                d2 = myfun(CHANGE,-2)          , d1=CHILDREN[which(CHANGE == d2)]) 
#df2
#   FAMILY      a1    a2      b1    b2     c1    c2     d1    d2
#   <fctr>  <fctr> <dbl>  <fctr> <dbl> <fctr> <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
#1 FAMILYA  ALFRED  5000  3000  KEVIN   PETE -1000  1000    JAKE
#2 FAMILYB MELISSA  1234   300  STEVE THOMAS -1111 -1022     DAN
#3 FAMILYC    ADAM  2131  1231 KELSEY   CAIT -1112  1000 BRANDON

# little clumpsy here... would like if someone could suggest a better way of uniting efficiently
df3 <- unite(df2, "A1", 2,3,sep = ":")
df4 <- unite(df3, "B1", 4,3,sep = ":")
df5 <- unite(df4, "c1", 4,5,sep = ":")
df6 <- unite(df5, "c1", 6,5,sep = ":")

#df6
#   FAMILY           A1           B1           c1         c1
#   <fctr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>      <chr>
#1 FAMILYA  ALFRED:5000  KEVIN:3000   PETE:-1000    JAKE:1000
#2 FAMILYB MELISSA:1234   STEVE:300 THOMAS:-1111    DAN:-1022
#3 FAMILYC    ADAM:2131 KELSEY:1231   CAIT:-1112 BRANDON:1000
```

Note : forgot to add TOTAL_CHANGE column 
add `TOTAL CHANGE  = sum(CHANGE)` inside `summarise()` and add +1 in unite() column indexes

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I really like the concept you are using here with dplyr. I don't think the values are correct though if you compare to the example above.

Comment: oh my god! how did i miss that! I'm sorry..fixing it!

Comment: I think you are taking the max-1 and min-1 for the whole list rather than by group which is causing the error. And thanks for looking into this!

Comment: This looks good, the only thing that is coming up as an error which I can makeshift is the last part for 2nd smallest by group, when you do `myfun(CHANGE,-2)` I think it is not starting from the bottom of the list but rather the top which is causing my answers to be NA

Comment: but that should not have happened. I have ensured that.. you ran on your actual data or the sample data shared here?

Comment: I ran it on my actual, it's probably a minor error on my end. It worked on the sample though, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using a custom function and `do` (from `dplyr`) to apply it to each family group. The custom function also uses `dplyr`.

First, the custom function generates (and sorts) the ordered changes. Then, it returns the total change (sum) along with the first and last two changes in the order. It has to return as a `data.frame` to work properly with `do`.

```
myFamFunction <- function(CHILDREN, CHANGE){
  toOut <-
    paste(CHILDREN, CHANGE, sep = ": ")[order(CHANGE, decreasing = TRUE)]

  c(sum(CHANGE)
    , head(toOut, 2)
    , tail(toOut, 2)) %>%
    rbind() %>%
    data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    setNames(c("Total Change"
               , "Biggest Change"
               , "Second Biggest Change"
               , "Second Smallest Change"
               , "Smallest Change"))
}
```

Note that this will likely throw an error if there are less than 2 children (though, if there are less than 4, the results are already going to be suspect). If you have more complicated actual data, telling us what you want to happen with it would allow protection against these edge cases.

Then, just `group_by`, pass the columns you want into the function, and voila:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(FAMILY) %>%
  do(myFamFunction(.$CHILDREN, .$CHANGE))
```

Returns:

```
   FAMILY `Total Change` `Biggest Change` `Second Biggest Change` `Second Smallest Change` `Smallest Change`
   <fctr>          <chr>            <chr>                   <chr>                    <chr>             <chr>
1 FAMILYA          10000     ALFRED: 5000             KEVIN: 3000               JAKE: 1000       PETE: -1000
2 FAMILYB           -499    MELISSA: 1234              STEVE: 300               DAN: -1022     THOMAS: -1111
3 FAMILYC           4252       ADAM: 2131            KELSEY: 1231            BRANDON: 1000       CAIT: -1112
```